# app crash after allocation of 10 mb memory

Tags: objective-c

We are facing crash in my app. I check on instrument that after allocation of 10 mb app get crash at any point(not any fix instance).

I am allocating approax 1000 label every time i click on any button in a for loop and release it after work done please help. In instrument there is no memory leaks but still app crash after allocationg 10 mb of memory.

this is a code i am applying on click of a button
is this a right way??????

```
-(IBACTION) btnShow
{ 

    for (UIView *obj in scrollview.subviews)
    {
        [obj removeFromSuperview];
    }

    int x;
    int y=0;

    for (int j=0; j<12; j++) {
        x=0;

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
            UILabel * lblUsage=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 75, 45)];
            lblUsage.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
            lblUsage.textColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
            lblUsage.numberOfLines=2;
            lblUsage.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
            lblUsage.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;        
            lblUsage.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"labelBox.png"]];
            lblUsage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
            lblUsage.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
            [scrollview addSubview:lblUsage];
            [lblUsage release];

            x+=75;
        }
        y+=40;
    }
    scrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(x, 1000);
}
```

Comment: nothing should be particular about 10 mb... maybe it is the allocation for the one for loop.. and the next time it crashes on allocation.. post your code where you do the for loop... and what error are you getting..SIGBART..EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Comment: i am not getting SIGBART..EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on ipad just it get crash suddenly after getting did receive memory warning level 2

Comment: code???..and it won't crash without an error..

Comment: Please post your code for how you're handeling the memory warning, i.e. `didReceiveMemoryWarning:`

Comment: okay ..try NSLog i in between the steps.. and check if for a particular value of i is there a crash or it happens anytime....on second thoughts... now i am thinking it is possible that your app is crashing because it might be getting memory warning..due to which system would terminate it.

Comment: Why is your IBAction in caps?

Comment: Just out of sheer curiosity, what are you actually using the 12000 UIlabels for?

Comment: i have already checked it is not done on any particular i value and on did receive memory warning i have done nothing because i need the variables in whole process

Comment: i have written wrong IBAction in stackoverflow it is already right in code and in this code in the place of value that i am assigning i am getting value from an array this is just a sample code problem is there in this loop.is uilabels removed permanently according to this code because i am getting did receive memory warning level 2.

Comment: This is why there is a table view and its controller. Its a subclass of scrollview. You should learn how to use it. Unless you're trying to prove some point.

Answer (score 2):

you receive **memory warning** in the above code

**memory warning level 1 is first warning where you should remove unnecessary view to clean up memory**

**memory warning level 2 is the limit.. remove something now or your app will quit within few seconds.**

**memory warning level 3 is sent when the system has decided to quit your app! due to memory usage**

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you'll just have to take a completely different aproach - which will
make your code much more complex. There's no way you could get around by creating
12.000 labels with pattern background.

- initially you would create only those labels that are shown on screen and one or
  two rows (and columns) of those that could soon appear on screen while the user is scrolling
- then you'll do most of your work in `viewDidScroll` by creating and disposing of lables on the fly.
  here your code should decide which labels can be disposed of (when they are far enough from visible screen)
  and which have to be created because they could appear soon on screen (depends on current location of content.
  offset)

Take a look at [ScrollViewSuite](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008904) as example for tiling. It's not exactly what you're looking
for but it should give you a kickstart.